# How to implement progress using IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progress-bar, ienumerable

I have a method that loops through an `IEnumerable` collection and passes each of them to another method. Something like:

```
void Run (object item)
{
    foreach(var method in this.Methods)
        method (item);
)
```

How can I implement sort of progress that will be reflected in a progress bar? I could do this easily if it was directly coded inside this method but this method is contained in a type outside the `ViewModel`, which I can call of course.

I just don't know how to implement it and get it from that method and reflect the changes in the UI, by passing it to `ViewModel`, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't let this recurse on you. If `Run` is inside `this.Methods`, you'll have a plate full of beeswax!

Comment: lol, what do you mean? this.Methods contains methods from many different static classes, but not itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by using events as follows.

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int m_CurrentProgress;
    private int m_MethodCount;

    // Bind this to the progress bar
    public int CurrentProgress
    {
        get { return m_CurrentProgress; }
        set
        {
            m_CurrentProgress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
        }
    }

    // Bind this to the progress bar
    public int MethodCount
    {
        get { return m_MethodCount; }
        set
        {
            m_MethodCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MethodCount");
        }
    }

    private void MethodExecuted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentProgress++;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var c = new ExternalClass();
        MethodCount = c.Methods.Count;
        c.MethodExecuted += MethodExecuted;

        c.Run(null);
    }
}

public class ExternalClass
{
    public List<object> Methods { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MethodExecuted;

    public void InvokeMethodExecuted(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = MethodExecuted;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void Run(object item)
    {
        foreach (var method in Methods)
        {
            method(item);

            InvokeMethodExecuted(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks btw the ExternalClass is static. Does that matter much? I can convert it, but not sure if the idea would still work.

Comment: Well ideally the class would be instantiated so that you dont have a static event which could be messy if you're running this multiple times on different threads etc. if thats not the case then you can make it static. Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

What I end up doing is passing in delegate used for reporting progress. This provides very nice decoupling. The delegate can be implemented as a lambda function that directly sets the progress on the form.

```
void Run (object item, Action<float> progress)
{ 
    int total = MethodCollection.Count; 
    int index = 0;
    foreach(var method in MethodCollection)
    {
        method (item);
        progress(index/(float)total);
    }
)
```

For long running tasks, I would do this on a separate thread using BackgroundWorker, which has built in hooks for progress reporting.

Comment: Can you please show me how this would be used? I am trying to see how Action would be specified in the caller, just for idea.