# When using a progress bar in Windows Forms, does the "lengthy process" have to run on a non-UI thread?

Tags: .net, winforms, progress-bar, ui-thread

When you use a progress bar, does it run in the UI thread? I ask because I wonder how you would display a progress bar for a lengthy task that is running *on the UI thread*.

I have some windows that take a while to open up and fully render, and I would like something to indicate to the user that something is happening. Some of them are impatient and if the UI goes unresponsive for 1/4 second, they start clicking around like mad.

I.E. the lengthy process isn't necessarily something I want to run in a background thread. So how would you display a progress bar in this case?

Comment: @Gabe: Not sure what you mean. This isn't just for when they open the app. There are many screens I would like to put an indicator on. Something like a simple marquee.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Application.DoEvents()` in the GUI thread to allow the progress bar to update, however this is discouraged due to re-entry issues and performance.
Your best bet really is a background thread.
This is made especially easy in the .NET framework with the `System.Threading.BackgroundWorker` class. [Msdn help on backgroundworkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: A background thread running the lengthy task? So you are saying I would need to take the lengthy task and run it in a background thread?

Comment: That would be the ideal solution yes. I however do understand your reluctance due to extra issues arising when using threading. :)

Comment: That and the fact that I would need to re-do a bunch of screens so they run their processes in the background . . .

Comment: If your users are not using windows seven, you could also try `Form.Refresh()` every now and then from your lengthy process...

Answer (score 2):

If it's a long running operation, it belongs in a background thread.  If it's an operation whose primary operation is to interact with UI elements, though, you might stuck with a small delay.

Note, though, that it's probably possible and advisable to separate the process from the UI ([MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) so it can be run on a background thread, so doing this will be healthy for the design of the app anyway.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. The process is heavily involved in interacting with the UI, so I just want a "hold your horses" indicator.

Comment: In that case, you're not going to be able to use a progress bar, because you have no way to update it.  Even if you change its progress programmatically, that won't affect the UI unless your method finishes.  You could add some sort of "please wait" label, but that means finding a way to give the UI rendering a chance to run in the middle of your code.  Maybe the Invalidate method?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx  Repaint might not happen until your method finishes, though.

Comment: I see. Even displaying an animated gif would be fine. Can I do that?

Comment: I tried playing around with this, and wasn't able to make it work.  The difficulty is getting UI stuff you do in your event handler to show up before your event handler finishes.  It might require some really fancy threading magic, and if it's not more than a second or two, it might not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the lengthy task on the UI thread, and show a progress bar at the same time.

However, you will lose the Win7/Vista animations on the progress bar, and if you don't run the message loop for five seconds, windows wil label your app as "unresponsive."

It is possible to update the progress bar both from a `BackgroundWorker` (it has special events for it), as well as from a function running on the UI thread. In the latter case, I pass in a delegate that can be called to update the progress bar.

One other thing: if you run on the UI thread, you can't implement a Cancel button that easily because your message pump is blocked.

So I reccomend a `BackgroundWorker` for longer tasks, For short tasks a splash screen might do as Gabe suggested in his comment.

Comment: How would I run a progress bar or marquee at the same time I am doing a lengthy task in the UI thread?

Comment: You can just open the window without blocking the UI thread. For more details begin with my answer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398084/how-to-implement-progress-using-ienumerable/5398198#5398198